# Background image not showing exactly as in image folder

Tags: css

My website shows the whole body as an image. The image is not showing exactly as the original in my image folder. Very close but not 100%. Is that because the image width and height itself is too big? I download them from a wallpaper website with resolution 2560x1500 should i get smaller.
I use a script that pulls an image from my img folder each page view or page refresh.
Thanks

Updated the body. The image shows the picture right but its not the full width.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add html code ?

Comment: That calls for the background image?

Comment: ya make the demo completely for more information you can add html code too. [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here is the website page https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/

Answer (score 0):

`min=1` and `max=360` is a range between the image shows.

below code get a **random number** between **min** and **max** value,

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
```

**Try this demo**

```js
changebg();

function changebg(){
   var min = 1, max = 360;
   min = Math.ceil(min);
   max = Math.floor(max);
   var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+"https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/img/"+ num + ".jpg"+")";
}
```

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The images are in a folder and get pulled by a script: <script type="text/javascript"> 
var bgcount = 370;
function changebg() {
  var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * bgcount);
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.capebretoncares.com/Start/img/' + num + '.jpg)';
}
</script>

Comment: `backgroundImage` change this to `background`

Comment: let me check bro :)

Comment: With that the image never changes

Comment: Rotating but the images still do not look how they do in the images folder.There bigger on the website you see less of the image.